# CryptoJS AES Encryption and Decryption

Tags: encryption, aes, cryptojs

First of all, I have 2 different systems - one in java, and one in javascript. I have an encrypted string (done in java), I also have secretKey which was used to encrypt it. I can decrypt it using this in Javascript. I know decryption result is correct. So I cant change decryption logic. Here is decryption code:

```
decrypt = (value) => {
  const cipher = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(value);
  const dec = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(
  CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
      { ciphertext: cipher },
      secretKey,
      { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding }
   )
 );
 return dec;
};
```

I am trying to encrypt the result of above to get original encrypted string in javascript. I tried to do exactly opposite of what I did in decrypt. Here is encryption code:

```
encrypt = (value) => {
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(
        CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            value, secretKey,
            { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding }
        )
  );
  const cipher = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted);
  return cipher;
```

}

I am expecting an original string which was passed in, but I am not getting same result.

```
let decrypted = decrypt("LJalEgQ81qUjrVzhlgFNw==");
console.log("Decrypted:", decrypted);

encrypted = encrypt(decrypted);
console.log("Encrypted:", encrypted);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You placement of `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse()` is incorrect. It should be inside the encrypt method, as `var encrypted=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(value), secretKey,
            { mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB, padding: CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding }
        )`

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. But now, I get an error `"wordArray.clamp is not a function"` on `Base64.stringify` in `encrypt`.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I had to use `encrypted.cipherText` before `Base64.stringify`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311514/how-to-decrypt-aes-with-cryptojs/66815024#66815024